# SSL Handshake for CNAME to Custom Domain in API Gateway fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using the Serverless framework together with the [serverless-domain-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-domain-manager) plugin to create an API with custom domain in AWS.

Suppose my custom domain is api.mycompany.com and I have multiple customers that want to access the api with CNAMES that include their names, for example customer1.api.mycompany.com and customer2.api.mycompany.com. I make sure to have a certificate that supports api.mycompany.com and also *.api.mycompany.com, so certificate-wise I am OK.

Now I create a CNAME for a customer, with name customer1.api.mycompany.com and value api.mycompany.com. When I try to access the api using the CNAME, the SSL handshake fails. if I add a Host header to the request with the value api.mycompany.com, all works well. According to AWS support (if I understand them correctly) this is because the CloudFront distribution created to support my custom domain is not aware of the CNAME.

My question - has anyone tried to do something similar? Any suggestions how to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Before I can suggest a workaround, I have questions for you: If this were working as you want, how would your API identify which customer endpoint was being accessed?  Also, how many unique customer endpoints are you planning? Five? Ten? Fifty? Hundreds?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, my plan is to identify the customer in the API Gateway Authorizer based on the host that was used to access the API, and provide this info, along with the user info to the API. The number of customers is going to be hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

This requires adding an [alternate domain name to CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#CreatingCNAME), which you can do so via the CloudFront console. It let's CloudFront know that it is fronting this secondary domain (in addition the one it already recognises).

The question did mention, but it's worth reiterating, that the certificate for your distribution must cover both domain names, [since this release](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/).